# weird conversion of polar coordinates into rectangular coordinates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

> Given $r=\frac{4}{1-\cos(\theta)}$, convert into rectangular (cartesian) coordinates.

My solution:

1. Square both sides: $r^2=\frac{16}{\sin^2(\theta)}$
2. Multiply the denominator by $r^2$ to get: $r^2\sin^2(\theta)=16$
3. Since $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we can make  $r^2\sin^2(\theta)=y^2$, thus $y^2=16$ or $y^2-16=0$

But the answer in the book does not match mine, can you explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So why does $(1-\cos(\theta))^2 = \sin^2(\theta)$ according to your computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in step 1, squaring both sides: note that
$$(1-\cos(\theta))^2\neq 1 - \cos^2(\theta).$$
The correct result of squaring both sides would be
$$r^2=\frac{16}{(1-\cos(\theta))^2}=\frac{16}{1-2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)}$$

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer is satisfactory, you should be able to click the green checkmark soon to "accept" it.

Comment: uh, actually I'm stuck since the expression you gave me does not bring me any closer to the answer in the book

Comment: Here's one correct approach:
$$\begin{align*}
r&=\frac{4}{1-\cos(\theta)}\\
r-r\cos(\theta)&=4\\
r&=4+r\cos(\theta)\\
r&=4+y\\
r^2&=16+8y+y^2\\
x^2+y^2&=16+8y+y^2\\
x^2-8y-16&=0
\end{align*}$$

Comment: just figured it out on my own  lol,thanks a lot for help though!

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Isn't $r\cos(\theta)$ usually $x$? It just means a rotation by $\pi/2$.

Comment: @robjohn: Oops, you're right - wasn't paying attention.